# How to change the color of the text in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, textcolor

I'm working on with a code but i cant seem to find where will i change the color of the text. Should i code it or no? If yes whats the proper code for changing the color of the text? Thanks you so much

Comment: are you talking about IDE text color?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the text with the theming or from the "preferences>font & colors" panel.

[image: font color panel]

Answer (score 0):

Click on Tools-> 
Then Click Options-> 
Then Click Fonts&Colors